# Shuffle piped through sed gives different number of lines

Tags: bash, sed, shuffle

I have a data file with thousands of lines, each consisting of 5 numbers. For example:

```
23 31 56 21 34
34 76 34 75 32
...
...
```

I want to write a bash script to select n% lines at random, and output them with the last entry set to 0. For the remainder of the entries I just want to output the line as it is. I don't care in which order the lines are output.

My attempt at doing this is to shuffle the file, then take the first n% of the lines and use `awk` to print them with a zero in the last place. Then I output the remainder of the lines. Here is my attempt:

```
#! /bin/bash
number=$2
numlines=$(less $1 | wc -l)
number=$(echo $number'*'$numlines | bc)
number=$(echo $number'/'100 | bc)

shuffledFile=$(less $1 | shuf)
# following line echos the shuffled file, gets the first $number lines, and prints them with a zero in the final column
echo "$shuffledFile" | sed -n --unbuffered "1,/$number/p" | awk '{print $1" "$2-7200" "$3" "$4" 0"}'
echo "$shuffledFile" | sed -n "/${number}/,/${numlines}/p" | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5}'
```

My problem is that each time I run this script a different number of lines are output. I have determined that if I don't shuffle the file, then it all works as expected. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong notation for printing lines with `sed`, it should be:

```
sed -n 'fromline,toline p'
```

Currently you are printing from line 1 to whichever line contains `/$number/`, or in the second case from the first line containing `/${number}/` to the following line containing `/${numlines}/` which, with random input, is rather unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Awk anyway, it's probably more clear to write

```
shuf $1 | awk 'NR <= '$number' {$5=0} {print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this python script as shuffle.py:

```
import sys
from random import shuffle
list1 = []
for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
  list1.append(line)
percent = 60
lim = percent  * len(list1) // 100
shuffle(list1)
for i,line in enumerate(list1):
  if i > lim :
    print line,
  else :
    print " ".join(line.split()[:4]),"0"
```

Usage : python shuffle.py file